# perl call not piping parameters to executable

Tags: perl, arguments, c-preprocessor

I am calling a cmd like:

```
perl ScriptGen.pl Target.c %PreProcessorPath%\preproc.exe Arg1 Arg2 > clean.c
```

And I get errors which mean Arg1 and Arg2 are not correctly passed to the pre processor.

I would like to call this perl script like this by having the target file, and preprocessor path itself as arguments to the perl script, and Arg1 Arg2 are arguments to the perl script which the preproc understands.

EDIT: There is a

```
my $cmd = shift @ARGV
```

at the begginning of the script to parse the arguments, and then the script works with that.

Comment: Perhaps instead you could work on making your question less confused / confusing?  It seems that probably your expectations are different from the documented behavior but we don't know what your expectations are.

Comment: @Jackson: Could you please explain `perl` file argument is this `target.c` or `preproc.exe` and how can we get the `arg1` & `arg2` for `perl` file. If you run this in the batch file `SET` the `PATH` for `PreprocessorPath\prepoc.exe` and the same `exe` having `Arg1` & `Arg2` parameters. How it is possible.

Comment: There is no pipe in that command

Comment: ok, perl input argument is the source file, which has to be modyfied, and the rest are arguments passed to the perl script (first one is the path to preprocessor, and next 2 ones are arguments directly passed to the preprocessor through the perl script)

Comment: `Target.c` you mean this is the `source file`

Answer (score 1):

This is my Suggestion:

You can use the `batchfile` instead of using in a single line several parameters with `applications`;

Create one batchfile - `scriptgen.bat`

```
 SETPATH=%PATH%;%PreProcessorPath%\preproc.exe  
 call preproc.exe %1 %2  
 rem %1 = Arg1 %2 = Arg1  %3 = Target.c 
 perl -w ScriptGen.pl %3 %1 %2 > clean.c
```

In MS-dos Prompt run:

```
 scriptgen.bat Arg1 Arg2 Arg3
```